# Null in getting the post value from Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, rest-client

I'm sending few values in ajax by Post method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/login',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        sessionId: '123',
        jCryptions: 'testdata'
    },
    success: function(response) {
    }
});
```

In web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.opentap.resource</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In Controller

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(@QueryParam("sessionId") String sessionId,@QueryParam("jCryptions") String encryptedString) throws IOException {
```

I've put sysout inside this. Every time it's returning the null value. I tried different methods to receive the data like changing the QueryParam and PathParam. But none worked. I can't figure out what is wrong here. But If I test it through rest-client in firfox by sending the data through url as POSt, it works. I need it be same on by using AjaX

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending JSON, $.ajax doesn't encode your data to json you have to do it yourself.

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    sessionId: '123',
    jCryptions: 'testdata'
}),
```

Comment: I've added the above code. But still I'm getting only the null values when displaying the data using @QueryParam which is shown in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `JSON` data,while in the rest service you are using `@Queryparam`,which extract data from query string.I think you will have to make below changes to your front and back end to make it work.

In the front end use `JSON.stringify()`,to convert value to `json` format

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/login',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
         sessionId: '123',
         jCryptions: 'testdata'
    }),
    success: function(response) {
    }
});
```

In the backend simply `@QueryParam` won't work,and i don't think there is any annotation in `JAX-RS` which can extract data directly from JSON ([See Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrst/index.html)).

So create a model class to represent your json data,like below.

```
@XmlRootElement
class JsonData{
 private String sessionId;
 private String jCryptions;

 //getter and setter
}
```

Now change your service to below.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(JsonData data) throws IOException {
   //---
}
```